# Serve files only if their extension is specified in Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, files

I'm running Apache on Ubuntu Server.
mysite.com/file.php, for example, is accessible also from mysite.com/file
and the same is for images, html pages and everything else.
How can I force Apache to serve files only if their extension is specified?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need disable MultiViews:

```
Options -MultiViews
```

> **The effect of MultiViews is as
>   follows:** if the server receives a
>   request for `/some/dir/foo`, if
>   `/some/dir` has MultiViews enabled,
>   and `/some/dir/foo` does not exist,
>   then the server reads the directory
>   looking for files named `foo.*`, and
>   effectively fakes up a type map which
>   names all those files, assigning them
>   the same media types and
>   content-encodings it would have if the
>   client had asked for one of them by
>   name. It then chooses the best match
>   to the client's requirements.

See these links for details:

- http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#options
- http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/content-negotiation.html#negotiation (scroll a bit until you see *Multiviews* header)